# How to get the characteristic(s) of HM-10 Bluetooth LE in iOS

Tags: ios, bluetooth, arduino, hm-10

I am trying to send some data from an iOS device to the HM-10 Bluetooth LE Module connected to an arduino. Problem is after connecting to the module `discoverServices` doesn't return a characteristic for the service.

```
    func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: NSError?) {
    if(error != nil) {
        print(error?.description)
    }
    for service in peripheral.services! {
        let thisService = service as CBService
        print("Service: \(thisService.description)")
        print("Characteristic: \(thisService.characteristics)")
    }
}
```

This outputs:

```
Service: <CBService: 0x137e84ea0, isPrimary = YES, UUID = FFE0>
Characteristic: nil
```

I am a beginner with this arduino stuff as well as iOS. So any suggestions would be welcome. Maybe there is a way to write to the bluetooth module without knowing the characteristic... I have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to get the answer. Because of my rudimentary understanding of the CoreBluetooth Framework I forgot to call `discoverCharacteristics` in `didDiscoverServices`. Well, I am really learning by doing. (I somehow thought `discoverServices` would call `discoverCharacteristics` itself.)